# How can I add events to Tapku Calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, calendar, tapku

I've attached the Tapku Calendar to my project. It works great. But I have to add events to my calendar from RSS or JSON data.  I didn't see any method in Tabku Lib about this issue.

How can I add events to Tapku Calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked with both TapKu and [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal). Honestly, I recommend using Kal over TapKu, because [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) offers callback methods designed to work with loading data from the web. I can't say the same for TapKu.

The TapKu documentation is [here](http://tapku.com/documentation/Protocols/TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource.html), but as you stated, there's no particular way to add data. With TapKu, you basically specify which days to show marks on the calendar, and handle changes to the selected date.

You can find more information about Kal at its [Wiki on GitHub](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/wiki/_pages).

Comment: Thank you very much Moshe. I'm going to try Kal.

Comment: Sure. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Dont forget to exercise the right to vote and select answers. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is great Lib! But it's hard to import my parsed array to calendar. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this delegate method :

```
-(NSArray *)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate
{
    // adds marks to the individual dates
    // return an array containing boolean values (YES/NO)
    // whether to mark the date[index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it tells me how to show marks on specific dates, but can you tell me how can i change the marker to be shown on tile.

Comment: Whatcha mean 'on tile' ? sorry, just checked inbox now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having no issue adding all my current events into the KAL calendar's data source, and changing the marker is very simple also. Although, it may be simple, some changes has to be done to the KAL.bundle file that you should have imported into your project/framework. It contains all the photos used to create KAL's view.

Anyways, you're going to want to go to KAL's directory and under KalTileView.m and it is there where you will find

```
} else { 
textColor = ........
shadowColor = .......
markerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kal.bundle/kal_marker.png"];
}
```

The above code is in the drawRect method.

Modifying the marker is fine.... but I found some difficulties importing several markers so I could randomly choose from the markers to display.... to make the app a little more colorful :P. But nope, didn't work.

Although, you can change the marker to another color if you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Go to this site to download the demo code, and also have the detail explanation of the method to add markers

Comment: Your answer should be explained here only. If you want to just provide a link please use comments.